I run code in Jupyter Lab but it changes my code
when i run Jupyter Lab gives me an error and modifies my code
I tried to run this part of code
file = pd.read_csv('./CIC-IDS-2017/file.csv').sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
file2 = pd.read_csv('./CIC-IDS-2017/file2.csv').sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

Jupyter lab gives me this error:

file2 =
pd.read_csv('./CIC-IDS-2017/file2.csv').sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True=True)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

if i refresh the page ,the code results as in the error and even if i fix it it gives me similar errors and change the code again as in the error.
Anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Your error message refers to code that is not in your description of what you are running. The error message has: drop=True=True in the line. Is this fixed now?

i run that code and it gives me this error. if i refresh the page ,in the notebook the code that i run previously changed in the one wrote in the error message. this is an example but after i run the code it also adds random characters to my code and change it
